# Error when compiling Apache and OpenSSL: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, openssl

We are getting an error when compiling Apache 2.4.39 from source, with OpenSSL 1.0.2 also from source:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/httpd-2.4.39/support'
/usr/src/httpd-2.4.39/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pthread    \
         -o ab  ab.lo       /usr/src/httpd-2.4.39/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /usr/src/httpd-2.4.39/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lm -L/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -ldl -lcrypto -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:73: recipe for target 'ab' failed
make[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
```

The configure command was as follows. The server is running Ubuntu 18.04. Would anyone be able to point to a solution please? Thanks for your help!

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/httpd --with-included-apr --disable-userdir --enable-status --enable-rewrite --enable-so --enable-mpms-shared --with-mpm=prefork --enable-deflate --enable-headers --enable-expires --with-ssl=/opt/openssl --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps --enable-mods-static=ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use OpenSSL 1.1.1. I was thrown off by searches which gave old advice saying not to use 1.1.1.

The Apache change log is a good place to find out what version is supported:
https://www.apachelounge.com/Changelog-2.4.html

Comment: The error you got doesn't look like a problem with using OpenSSL 1.0.2 *per se*; rather, that the build open OpenSSL 1.0.2 you were attempting to link against was broken.